# Having issues with Multi-Time Frame input

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm a novice coder who needs help.
How am I able to add the `input.timeframe()` here? I'm having problems with all the aspects of the `request.security()` part with the `ma_function()`. I want to be able to lock the ATR Values to the timeframe inputed, instead of changing whenever I change timeframes

Here is all the code I have so far. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you for your time!

```
atr_ma = input.string(group="ATR - Average True Range", title="Smoothing:", defval="RMA", options=["RMA", "SMA", "EMA", "WMA"])
    atr_lenght = input.int(group="ATR - Average True Range", title="Lenght:", defval=14, minval=1)
    atr_multiply = input.int(group="ATR - Average True Range", title="Multiplier:", defval=2, minval=1)

color_atrText = color.silver
color_atrLow = color.teal
color_atrHigh = color.red

ma_function(source, atr_lenght) =>
    if atr_ma == "RMA"
        ta.rma(source, atr_lenght)
    else
        if atr_ma == "SMA"
            ta.sma(source, atr_lenght)
        else
            if atr_ma == "EMA"
                ta.ema(source, atr_lenght)
            else
                ta.wma(source, atr_lenght)
                
atrValue = ma_function(ta.tr(true), atr_lenght) * atr_multiply
atrValueHigh = ma_function(ta.tr(true), atr_lenght) * atr_multiply + high
atrValueLow = low - ma_function(ta.tr(true), atr_lenght) * atr_multiply

var table AtrTable = table.new(position.bottom_center, 3, 1, border_width = 3)   
f_fillCell(_table, _column, _row, _value, _timeframe) =>
    _cellText = _timeframe+ str.tostring(_value, "#.#")
    table.cell(_table, _column, _row, _cellText, text_color = color_atrText)
    table.cell_set_text_color(AtrTable, 1, 0, color.new(color_atrLow, transp = 0))
    table.cell_set_text_color(AtrTable, 2, 0, color.new(color_atrHigh, transp = 0))
    
if barstate.islast and show_atr == "On"
    f_fillCell(AtrTable, 0, 0, atrValue, "ATR: ")
    f_fillCell(AtrTable, 1, 0, atrValueLow, "L: " )
    f_fillCell(AtrTable, 2, 0, atrValueHigh, "H: ")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you want

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

i_res = input.timeframe('D', "Resolution", options=['D', 'W', 'M'])
atr_ma = input.string(group="ATR - Average True Range", title="Smoothing:", defval="RMA", options=["RMA", "SMA", "EMA", "WMA"])
atr_lenght = input.int(group="ATR - Average True Range", title="Lenght:", defval=14, minval=1)
atr_multiply = input.int(group="ATR - Average True Range", title="Multiplier:", defval=2, minval=1)

color_atrText = color.silver
color_atrLow = color.teal
color_atrHigh = color.red

ma_function(source, atr_lenght) =>
    if atr_ma == "RMA"
        ta.rma(source, atr_lenght)
    else
        if atr_ma == "SMA"
            ta.sma(source, atr_lenght)
        else
            if atr_ma == "EMA"
                ta.ema(source, atr_lenght)
            else
                ta.wma(source, atr_lenght)

                
atrValue = request.security("", i_res,  ma_function(ta.tr(true), atr_lenght) * atr_multiply)
atrValueHigh = request.security("", i_res, ma_function(ta.tr(true), atr_lenght) * atr_multiply + high)
atrValueLow = request.security("", i_res, low - ma_function(ta.tr(true), atr_lenght) * atr_multiply)

var table AtrTable = table.new(position.bottom_center, 3, 1, border_width = 3)   
f_fillCell(_table, _column, _row, _value, _timeframe) =>
    _cellText = _timeframe+ str.tostring(_value, "#.#")
    table.cell(_table, _column, _row, _cellText, text_color = color_atrText)
    table.cell_set_text_color(AtrTable, 1, 0, color.new(color_atrLow, transp = 0))
    table.cell_set_text_color(AtrTable, 2, 0, color.new(color_atrHigh, transp = 0))
    
if barstate.islast 
    f_fillCell(AtrTable, 0, 0, atrValue, "ATR: ")
    f_fillCell(AtrTable, 1, 0, atrValueLow, "L: " )
    f_fillCell(AtrTable, 2, 0, atrValueHigh, "H: ")
```

if not please elaborate